# Database not outputting on C even though I'm saving

Tags: c, output

I am doing an Order's Database in which in this case deals with a transaction.

The procedure is as follows:

1. First the Customer enters his ID. If it is not found, it exits to the main menu otherwise it proceeds (The Customer MUST have an ID registered within the database which is stored on another file)
2. It asks which Product they are going to buy (it asks for PRODUCT NAME [that's how lecturer wanted it by Name] and if it is not found it exists otherwise it proceeds
3. It asks how many they are going to buy and checks whether there is enough in Stock. If it is it proceeds otherwise asks the user whether they want to input another number or exit
4. Price is calculated automatically and a Confirmation is ASKED. if Customer CONFIRMS then the saving is done otherwise it exits to Main Menu

Now my problem is that even though my STRUCT is saving, whenever I come to output ANY ORDER in the database (for now testing as I need the LAST order of a customer first) The Database is always showing as EMPTY. Below is the Coding [it is rather long I am sorry but I cannot understand where is wrong] and also will provide the List All function.

Screenshots are provided as well to understand better how the program works:

```
void customerOrder()
{
    int checkID = 0; //variable to hold the ID input
    char ch;
    char ch1;
    char ch2;
    char option;
    char tempName [100];
    int  order = 0;
    int  tempStock = 0;
    float tempPrice = 0;



    printf ("\n\n\n\n\t\t    ************* Add Customer Order *************\n \n \n");

    // ----------- LOADING OF THE 3 DATA FILES -----------//
    if ((ofp = fopen ("orders.dat","a+b")) == NULL)
    {
        fputs   ("Error! Cannot open orders.dat\n",stderr);
        system  ("PAUSE");
        orderMainMenu();
    }
    rewind (ofp);

    if ((cfp = fopen ("customers.dat","r"))== NULL)
    {
        fputs ("Error! Cannot open customers.dat\n",stderr);
        system ("PAUSE");
        orderMainMenu();
    }
    rewind (cfp);

    if ((pfp = fopen ("products.dat","r+b"))== NULL)
    {
        fputs ("Error! Cannot open products.dat\n",stderr);
        system ("PAUSE");
        orderMainMenu();
    }
    rewind (pfp);

    //-------- Confirm whether to start Order ------------//
    printf ("WARNING: In order for an Order to be made, the Customer must be in the Database\n");
    printf ("Are you sure you want to continue? Y or N\n");
    while (getchar() !='\n')
    {
    }
    ch1 = getchar ();
    if (ch1 == 'Y' || ch1 == 'y')
    {
        // ---- INPUT OF CUSTOMER ID --------------//
        printf ("\nPlease Enter ID: ");

            while (scanf ("%d",&checkID) == 0)
            {
                printf ("\n\nInvalid Input!!!\n");
                printf ("Either you have entered a Letter!!\n");
                printf ("Press 'Y' to enter another ID or any key to return to MainMenu\n\n");
                while (getchar()!='\n')
                    {
                    }
                option = getchar();
                if (option == 'Y' || option == 'y')
                {
                    printf ("\nPlease Enter Another ID Number:\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf ("\nReturning to Order Management Menu\n");
                    system ("PAUSE");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    orderMainMenu();

                }
            }
            //---------- CHECK WHETHER ID EXISTS OTHERWISE EXIT TO MENU --------------//
            while (fread (&c, STRUCTSIZEC,1,cfp) == 1)
            {
                if (c.ID == checkID)
                {

                    clrscr();
                    printf ("\n\n\n\n\t\t    ************* Add Customer Order *************\n \n \n");

                    // SHOWS WHICH ID IS BEING SERVED //
                    printf ("\n\nNew Order For ID: %d\n", c.ID);


                    // ASKS WHICH PRODUCT TO BUY //
                    printf ("\nWhich Product do you want to buy?\n\n");
                    printf ("WARNING! Product Name is CASE SENSITIVE:\n");

                    // INPUT NAME //
                    printf ("Product Name: ");
                    while (getchar() !='\n')
                    {
                    }

                    fgets  (tempName, 100, stdin);
                    while (fread (&p, STRUCTSIZEP,1,pfp)== 1)
                    {
                        if (strncmp (tempName,p.pName,sizeof(tempName)) == 0)
                        {


                    // --- SHOWING ID and WHICH PRODUCT CUSTOMER IS GOING TO BUY -- //
                    clrscr ();
                    printf ("\n\n\n\n\t\t    ************* Add Customer Order *************\n \n \n");
                    printf ("Order for ID: %d\n", c.ID);
                    printf ("Product Name: %s\n\n", p.pName);

                    tempStock = p.pStock;

                    printf ("How many do you wish to buy?\n");
                    printf ("Currently there is %d in Stock", tempStock);
                    printf ("Order:  ");

                    while (scanf ("%d",&order) == 0)
                    {
                        printf ("Invalid Order! Only Numbers are  allowed!\n");
                        while (getchar() !='\n')
                        {
                        }
                    }
                    //---- CHECK WEHTHER ORDER IS BIGGER THAN WHAT IS FOUND IN STOCK ----//
                    //---- IF YES ASK IF USER WANTS TO INPUT ANOTHER NUMBER OR EXIT ----//
                    while (order > tempStock)
                    {
                        printf ("There is not enough items in Stock to satisfy that quantity!\n");
                        printf ("Do you want to enter another quantity? 'Y' for yes, any key to return to Menu\n");
                        fflush (stdin);
                        ch2 = getchar();
                        if (ch2 == 'Y' || ch2 == 'y')
                        {
                            printf ("Please enter another quantity:\n");
                            scanf ("%d",&order);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf ("Order Canceled! Returning to Main Menu");
                            system ("PAUSE");
                            fclose (cfp);
                            fclose (ofp);
                            fclose (pfp);
                            orderMainMenu();
                        }
                    }

                    printf ("\nTotal Price for this Order will be:\n");
                    tempPrice = (order * p.pPrice);
                    printf ("Total: %.2f\n", tempPrice);

                    // ---- SHOW THE TRANSACTION OF THE USER AND ASK WHETHER TO CONFIRM ---- //
                    clrscr();
                    printf ("\n\n\n\n\t\t    ************* Add Customer Order *************\n \n \n");

                    printf ("This is the Customer's Overview of Purchase:\n\n");
                    printf ("Customer's ID: %d\n",c.ID);
                    printf ("Customer's Product: %s",p.pName);
                    printf ("Order: %d\n",order);
                    printf ("Total Price: %.2f\n\n",tempPrice);

                    printf ("\n\n----------------------------------------\n\n");
                    printf ("Are you sure you of this transaction?\n");
                    printf ("Warning: After Confirming you cannot change the Order!\n");
                    printf ("Press 'Y' to confirm the Transaction otherwise press 'N' to cancel the order and return to Main Menu\n");

                    while (getchar() !='\n')
                    {
                    }

                    ch = getchar();
                    if (ch == 'N' || ch == 'n')
                     {
                         printf ("Transaction CANCELLED! Returning to Order Main Menu!\n");
                         system ("PAUSE");
                         orderMainMenu();
                     }
                     else if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
                     {
                         tempStock = (tempStock - order);
                         p.pStock = tempStock; //Updates the new stock number in Products' Database
                         fseek (pfp,-STRUCTSIZEP,SEEK_CUR);
                         fwrite(&p, STRUCTSIZEP,1,pfp);
                         fclose (pfp);

                         o.quantity = order;
                         o.cID = c.ID;
                         o.price = tempPrice;
                         strncpy(o.pName,p.pName, sizeof(p.pName));
                         o.timer = time(NULL);

                         fwrite (&o,STRUCTSIZEO,1,ofp);
                         fclose (ofp); //Closing of Files
                         fclose (cfp);
                         fclose (pfp);

                         printf("The Transaction Order saved is as follows:\n");
                         printf("ID: %d\nProduct: %sQuantity: %d\nPrice: %.2f\n",o.cID,o.pName,o.quantity,o.price);
                         printf("Transaction Made at: %s\n",asctime(localtime(&o.timer)));
                         system ("PAUSE");
                         orderMainMenu();
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Returning to Order Main Menu\n");
        system ("PAUSE");
        orderMainMenu();
    }
}
```

ListAll method:

```
void oListAll()
{
    order o;

    printf ("\n\n\n\n\t\t    ********** Current Products in the Database *******\n \n \n");

    //--------------- LOADING OF FILE ------------ //
    if ((ofp = fopen ("orders.dat","rb")) == NULL)
    {
        fputs ("Cannot open products.dat file!\n",stderr);
        printf ("Returning to Order Main Menu\n");
        system ("PAUSE");
        orderMainMenu();
    }
    rewind (ofp);

    // --------- START TO TRAVERSE THE DATABASE AND OUTPUT DATA -------- //
    printf ("Current Orders in the Database:\n");
    while (fread (&o, STRUCTSIZEO,1,pfp)==1)
    {
        printf (" Name: %s Price: %.2f\n In Stock: %d\n\n", o.pName, o.price, o.quantity);
    }
    system ("PAUSE");
    productMainMenu();

}
```

These are the screenshots:

1. http://tinypic.com/r/110x7c2/6
2. http://tinypic.com/r/1446ya/6
3. http://tinypic.com/r/315iy3s/6
4. http://tinypic.com/r/15xo4lt/6
5. http://tinypic.com/r/2ze9wfr/6
6. http://tinypic.com/r/jtx8xw/6

I know it's rather long but please bear with me, I've been over 4 hours trying to figure out what's wrong with it.  Thanks a bunch

Comment: Does the output file actually contain any data?

Comment: Yes it does, when I tried to open it there was the name and the surname of the user and a bunch of garbage NULL but yes Data IS There. In fact after i Finish the transaction it outputs what it has been bought and so. and all are taken from the struct and it outputs perfectly

Comment: Why is this you're using the variable `pfp` in your output function, when you have opened the file using the variable `ofp`? And where are the declarations of these vars, btw.

Comment: This is just one function not the whole "class" there are other functions like the menu and certain variables declarations which are outside, if you want I can email you the whole file or smth

Comment: One issue I see is in customerOrder() you only close the files on success. You need to make sure all file pointers are closed in all cases.

Comment: when it goes into the mainMenu it closes them all I've set it myself

Comment: I don't get it, because the PRODUCT file updates successfully and so! It's just this one that doesn't want to work

Answer (score 1):

Your `oListAll()` function opens `FILE *ofp`, but reads from `pfp`. Try reading from `ofp`

Comment: Still Nothing, The database is still outputting nothing

Answer (score 1):

As this is not the whole program I can't find the issue but my guess it that it has something to do with your file pointers being global vars. You should make them local and always ensure they are closed properly.

I would break up the customerOrder() function in to smaller functions. This will make your code much easier to read, debug, and modify. For example (this is just pseudo-code, you have to fill in the blanks):

```
void customerOrder()
{
    int checkId = getCustomerID(); // Checks the DB to see if user exists
    bool productExists = checkProduct(tempName); // Checks the DB to see if product exists
    int productCount = getProductCount(tempName);  // Checks the DB to get count of items in stock
    saveOrder(checkId, tempName, order);  // Save the order
}

// Save the order in DB. Ensures FILE pointers are closed when done
void saveOrder(int customerID, const char * productName, int count)
{
    order o;
    // Create the order here....
    FILE *ofp = fopen ("orders.dat","ab");
    if (NULL != ofp) {
        fwrite (&o,STRUCTSIZEO,1,ofp);
        fclose (ofp); //Closing of Files
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my problem is that it is not saving, I"m checking the orders file and it is still 8 bytes only

Comment: Please tell us the definition of `order o` and `STRUCTSIZEO`

Comment: order o is a "copy" of a struct which contains
name, customerID, price, quantity and time_t (for time stamp)
STRUCTSIZEO is sizeof (order)

Comment: Is there a way where I can upload the whole coding as a one file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/t251aARf  - This is the orderManagement, if you need other files tell me and I will paste them

Comment: One thing I didn't notice before is when you never return from customerOrder(). Instead you call orderMainMenu(). You should instead use a "return" statement.

Comment: so return is the same as going back to the orderMainMenu()? my structure for looping is a bit different and has always worked for now, it's just the saving that's not working

Comment: Return jumps back to the calling function. Which is what you want. You keep calling a new instance of the  orderMainMenu(). That's not what you want. This may or may not be that cause of your problem. It's just wrong.

Comment: Another look and I think the issue is rewind (ofp); You open the file for append but then rewind it which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Still nothing, I removed the ofp but It's not appending It's like it is not saving

Comment: If you want I can provide you everything, BUT
all is working apart from this

Comment: Why don't you look at the code in the debugger? Just set a breakpoint to where the order is being written to orders.dat, check what's being written (and how many bytes). If this seems to be ok, check what happens later to the file. I guess that the file will be crippled later by one of the fopen()s or rewind()s.

Comment: Will check though I can't figure out how the Eclipse debugger works